# Show that it is possible to guarantee a win by buying $14$ tickets.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, hypergraphs

> You enter a lottery by picking a subset of three numbers from $\{1,2,3,4 \dots 14\}$
>   . You win a prize if you match at least two of the numbers on the winning ticket.
>
> Show that it is possible to guarantee a win by buying $14$ tickets. (Hint: Use the $(7, 7, 3, 3, 1)$- design.)

---

If we make sure to have every pair appear once in the design, we are guaranteed a win.

I am not sure how this can be done using the $(7,7,3,3,1)$-design. We need $14$ elements, not $7$.

I gather we need a $(14,14,r, 3, 1)$-design, but then $r$ is not an integer.

---

(BTW, this is from Combinatorics by Mazur)

Comment: What does " [14]" mean???

Comment: $[n]$ is the set of integers $1,2,3, \dots, n$.

Comment: Yes, but it says " [14]" :-)

Comment: $[14]=\{x \in \mathbb Z : 1\le x \le 14\}$

Comment: I guess the problem must have been that your browser didn't display the control character that barak and I were seeing. I've removed it; now it just says "[14]" as intended :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either two numbers come from $1-7$, or two numbers come from $8-14$.

Comment: So, two separate sets of the $(7,7,3,3,1)$-design?